# FragmentManager has not been attached to a host

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Below is my code. When I am trying to run the app on a tablet in two pane mode, App is crashing and I get Exception:

> FragmentManager has not been attached to a host

I debugged the app and I get this message when trying to create fragmentManager:

> Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot
>   evaluate androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.toString())

I tried all the solutions from similar questions but nothing worked for me. Can anyone help?

```
package com.example.Palaver.friend;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.Palaver.Database_Room_Entities.friendEntity;
import com.example.Palaver.festStringVariable;
import com.example.splashtest.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class Friend_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <Friend_Adapter.friendHolder> implements festStringVariable {

    final friend parent;
      private List<friendEntity> friends =new ArrayList<>();

    private final View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            friendEntity friendentity = (friendEntity) view.getTag();
            Context context = view.getContext();
            if (friend.TwoPanemode) {

                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString(ChatDetailFragment.ARG_FRIENDS_NAME, friendentity.getFriend());
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = parent.getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                ChatDetailFragment fragment = new ChatDetailFragment();

                fragment.setArguments(arguments);

                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.chat_acticity, fragment)
                        .commit();
            } else {
                 context = view.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatActicityFragement.class);
                intent.putExtra(ChatDetailFragment.ARG_FRIENDS_NAME, friendentity.getFriend());

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }




            //*********************************






              /*  // In portrait
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatActicityFragement.class);
                intent.putExtra(UserNameS_Extra, friend.UserName);
                intent.putExtra(PASSWORD_Extra, friend.Password);
                intent.putExtra(FRIEND_NAME_EXTRA, friendentity.getFriend());
                context.startActivity(intent);*/
            }



    };


    Friend_Adapter(friend parent){
        this.parent=parent;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public friendHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.friend_single_item,parent,false);
        return new friendHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull friendHolder holder, int position) {
      friendEntity friEntity = friends.get(position);
      holder.friendNmae.setText(friEntity.getFriend());
        holder.itemView.setTag(friends.get(position));
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return friends.size();
    }


    public void setFriends(List<friendEntity> friends){
        this.friends=friends;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public friendEntity getFriendAt(int position){
        return friends.get(position);

    }



    class friendHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private  TextView friendNmae;


        public friendHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            friendNmae = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.friend_image_id);
        }
    }



}
```

here is the Exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager has not been attached to a host.
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1725)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:321)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:286)
        at com.example.Palaver.friend.Friend_Adapter$1.onClick(Friend_Adapter.java:48)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: You're getting the fragment manager from the `parent` variable which is only assigned at creation of the adapter. Where does `parent` itself get the FragmentManager?
Keep in mind, that when you switch from single-mode to the multi task mode, the activity is destroyed and recreated. Therefore, you might need to get a new FragmentManager.

Comment: Thanks guys , both answers help me , the problem was that I did not pass the parameter parent from the friend activity correctly , I was passing a new instance from friend class instead of passing this.